# Initialisation list for an member object without default constructor

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I read about references and objects that are initialised in a class. However, I couldn't find a clear statement, except for hints, to the following question:

Can I initialise a member object `obj1` in an initialisation list if it doesn't have a default constructor (no `Object(){}`)?

```
class Sample
{
private:
      Object1 obj1(arguments);
public:
     Sample(Object1 o1)  : obj1( o1(arguments) )
     { }
};
```

The question came up, because if have a problem related to this [How can I initialize C++ object member variables in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927169/how-can-i-initialize-c-object-member-variables-in-the-constructor). The code is taken form there as well. Thanks for your effort.

Daniel

**EDIT:**

Since the answer suggest that it works, a test returned an error (which is exactly the reason I ask this question):

```
../src/Timestep.h:45:12: error: field ‘myFEMSolver’ has incomplete type FEMSolver myFEMSolver;
```

Code:

```
class Timestep {
public:
  Timestep();
private:
  FEMSolver myFEMSolver;
}

Timestep::Timestep() : myFEMSolver(*this)
  { //do some stuff
}

FEMSolver::FEMSolver(const Timestep& theTimestep) : myTimestep(theTimestep)
  { //do some stuff
}

main(){
  Timestep myTimestep();
}
```

Comment: That code does not produce that error.  Namely, you get that error when the `FEMSolver` class itself is declared but not defined at the point that `TimeStep` is defined.  `FEMSolver` must be defined fully first.  This has nothing whatsoever to do with initializer lists.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: In fact it is not a XY problem. The original question was important to realise that what I intend to do would actually work. But you were right about the declaration. I switched come header an now it works. Thanks you very much.

Comment: X was "what is producing this incomplete type error". Y is "Can I initialize a member object in an initialization list if it doesn't have a default constructor "  This is _very much_ an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I initialise a member object `obj1` in an initialisation list if it doesn't have a default constructor (no `Object(){}`)?

Yes. In fact, you *must* do so.

```
class Sample
{
    private:

        Object1 obj1;

    public:

        Sample() : obj1( /* ctor args */ )
        {
        }
};
```

If you're passing another `Object1` to your `Sample` constructor, and passing that to `Object1`'s copy constructor, then you probably want to pass it by reference:

```
Sample(const Object1& o) : obj1(o)
{
}
```

If `Object1` doesn't have a no-argument constructor, and you don't initialize `obj1` in the initializer list, you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class declaration as follows:

```
class Sample
{
private:
      Object1 obj1;
public:
     Sample(const Object1& o1)  : obj1(o1)
     { }
};
```

To call the `Sample` constructor use:

```
Sample s(Object1(arguments));
```

This requires, that your `Object1` is a so called *nice* class (provides copy constructor and assignment operator).
For any other case you'll need to use a reference or pointer of `Object1` as member in the `Sample` class.

Another (easier) way is to pass the arguments through:

```
class Sample
{
private:
      Object1 obj1;
public:
     Sample(Args& arguments)  : obj1(arguments)
     { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you either want to give an existing `Object1` in a list-initializer, or make an `Object1` inside a nested list-initializer, unless `Object1`'s constructor is explicit. So let's say we have

```
struct Object1
{
    Object1(int, int) { };
};
```

Then the most generic way to initialize `Object1` within `Sample` by copy, move, or its own arguments without ambiguities is:

```
class Sample
{
private:
    Object1 obj1;
public:
    Sample(Object1&& o1) : obj1(std::move(o1)) { }
    Sample(const Object1& o1) : obj1(o1) { }

    template<
        typename... A,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<Object1, A...>{}>
    >
    Sample(A&&... a) : obj1(std::forward<A>(a)...) { }
};
```

This allows us a variety of `Sample` constructions:

```
int main ()
{
    Object1 o1{1, 2};
    const Object1& o2{o1};
    Sample s1{Object1{1, 2}};
    Sample s2{{1, 2}};
    Sample s3{1, 2};
    Sample s4{o1};
    Sample s5{o2};
}
```

If `Object1`'s constructor is `explicit`, then `s2` is not allowed. Depending on what you want to support, you can of course simplify `Sample` in a number of ways.