# Creating a default constructor for a struct within a struct?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a default constructor for a struct and setting all values to 0, but there is a substruct and value (Date birthDate) referenced and I'm not sure how to handle it.

The Date struct includes 3 integers: day, month, year. Combined they = birthDate.

```
Reptile::Reptile(){
    species = " ";
    DangerAssessment dangerAssess = "";
    Date birthDate() = 0;
    SizeOfEnclosure sizeofenclosure;
    exhibitName = " ";
    }
```

Comment: cant you assign it with something like `Date birthdate = Date(0,0,0)` ?

Comment: [Use the Member initializer list.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Should look something like `Reptile::Reptile(): species(""), dangerAssess(""), birthDate(0), sizeofenclosure(0), exhibitName("") { }` If you are calling default constructors you can leave them out. They will be default constructed. [mcve] required for more specific information.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I'm afraid not. That would make and initialize an Automatic variable scoped to only exist within the body of the constructor. It would not initialize or assign a member variable.

Comment: Duplicate-ish: [How can I initialize C++ object member variables in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927169/how-can-i-initialize-c-object-member-variables-in-the-constructor)

Comment: @Hannah but its ok to have it be `Date birthDate() = 0` what do you want to be there?