# Cant build a wrapper class for Encoder.h, Encoder constructor has been called before wrapper class constructor is called

Tags: arduino-c++

this is my *MotorEncoder.h*

```
#include <Encoder.h>

class MotorEncoder {
public:
    MotorEncoder(int pin1, int pin2);
    void init();
    int read();

private:
    int pin1;
    int pin2;
    Encoder encoder;
};
```

And this is *MotorEncoder.cpp*

```
#include "MotorEncoder.h"

MotorEncoder::MotorEncoder(int pin1, int pin2) {
    this->pin1 = pin1;
    this->pin2 = pin2;
    this->encoder = Encoder(pin1, pin2);
}

void MotorEncoder::init() {
}

int MotorEncoder::read() {
}
```

I get always an error stated that I call Encoder with 0 parameters.

```
In file included from src/encoder/MotorEncoder.h:5:0,
                 from src/encoder/MotorEncoder.cpp:1:
/Users/slawalata/.platformio/lib/Encoder_ID129/Encoder.h:72:2: note: candidate: Encoder::Encoder(uint8_t, uint8_t)
  Encoder(uint8_t pin1, uint8_t pin2) {
  ^
/Users/slawalata/.platformio/lib/Encoder_ID129/Encoder.h:72:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

It breaks in compilation time. I haven't called this constructor at all.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927169/how-can-i-initialize-c-object-member-variables-in-the-constructor), i change my code to :

*MotorEncoder.h*

```
class MotorEncoder {

    public:
    MotorEncoder(int pin1, int pin2);

    void init();

    int read();

    private:
        int pin1;
        int pin2;
        Encoder* encoder;
};
```

MotorEncoder.cpp

```
MotorEncoder::MotorEncoder(int pin1, int pin2) {
    this->pin1 = pin1;
    this->pin2 = pin2;
    this->encoder = new ::Encoder(pin1, pin2);
}

void MotorEncoder::init() {
}

int MotorEncoder::read() {
    return encoder->read();
}
```

Many thanks,