# Add class members dynamically

Tags: oop, constructor, arduino, arduino-c++

For my Arduino project, I want to have a class called `Buttons`, that has six [EasyButton](https://easybtn.earias.me/) instances as members. I want to pass the pins of the EasyButton instances to the `Buttons` constructor. How can I instantiate the six `EasyButton` members of my `Buttons` class in the `Buttons` constructor?

```cpp
#include <EasyButton.h>


uint32_t debounce_time = 200;
bool pullup_enable = true;
bool active_low = true;

class Buttons
{
private:

public:
  Buttons(uint8_t pin1, uint8_t pin2, uint8_t pin3, uint8_t pin4, uint8_t pin5, uint8_t pin6);
  // do the following in the constructor.
  EasyButton button1{pin1, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
  EasyButton button2{pin2, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
  EasyButton button3{pin3, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
  EasyButton button4{pin4, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
  EasyButton button5{pin5, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
  EasyButton button6{pin6, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low};
};
```

Comment: Use an initialiser list.

Comment: Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927169/how-can-i-initialize-c-object-member-variables-in-the-constructor). I won't call it a duplicate since the  question is different even though the answer is the same.

Comment: Can you clarify some ? Do you want to pass ````pin1```` on to the constructor of ````button1```` etc. ? (What john says, move the c-tor call from the class body into a initializer list)

Comment: Initializer list was what I was looking for (perfect example from @user253751). Sorry my question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with an *initialiser list*

```
class Buttons
{
private:

public:
  Buttons(uint8_t pin1, uint8_t pin2, uint8_t pin3, uint8_t pin4, uint8_t pin5, uint8_t pin6);
  EasyButton button1;
  EasyButton button2;
  EasyButton button3;
  EasyButton button4;
  EasyButton button5;
  EasyButton button6;
};

  Buttons::Buttons(uint8_t pin1, uint8_t pin2, uint8_t pin3, uint8_t pin4, uint8_t pin5, uint8_t pin6)
      : button1(pin1, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low),
        button2(pin2, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low),
        button3(pin3, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low),
        button4(pin4, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low),
        button5(pin5, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low),
        button6(pin6, debounce_time, pullup_enable, active_low)
  {
  }
```